# function is being redefined somewhere and I cannot see where I am doing it

Tags: c++

I am getting this error and I can not figure it out can someone please help explain what I am doing wrong? I have tried removing some of the include statements as well as creating a makefile for my project but I keep getting the same errors

This is my Token.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum TokenType {
        // Reserved Words:
        VOID_TOKEN, MAIN_TOKEN, INT_TOKEN, COUT_TOKEN
    };

// IMPORTANT: The list above and the list below MUST be kept in sync.
const std::string gTokenTypeNames[] = {
        "VOID", "MAIN", "INT", "COUT"
    };

class TokenClass {

private:
    TokenType mType;
    std::string mLexeme;

public:
    TokenClass();
    TokenClass(TokenType type, const std::string &lexeme);

    TokenType GetTokenType() const { 
        return mType; 
    }
};
```

This is my Token.cpp file

```
#include "Token.h"

TokenClass::TokenClass() {
}

TokenClass::TokenClass(TokenType type, const std::string &lexeme) {
    mType = type;
    mLexeme = lexeme;
}

TokenType TokenClass::GetTokenType() const {
    return mType; 
}
```

and here is my Main.cpp file

```
#include "Token.h"

int main() {
    TokenType tt = VOID_TOKEN;
    std::string lexeme = "void";
    TokenClass tok1(tt, lexeme);
    // std::cout << tok1 << std::endl;
}
```

and here are the errors I am getting

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g main.cpp Token.cpp -o Token
Token.cpp:11:11: error: redefinition of ‘TokenType TokenClass::GetTokenType() const’
 TokenType TokenClass::GetTokenType() const {
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from Token.cpp:1:
Token.h:40:12: note: ‘TokenType TokenClass::GetTokenType() const’ previously defined here
  TokenType GetTokenType() const {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:8: main] Error 1
```

Comment: It tells you exactly what's re-defined. Your function `GetTokenType()` was implemented in the header **and** implementation file.

Comment: What am I doing wrong -> not reading the error message :)

Comment: That code was given to me by a professor to be put in my header file so I assumed it somehow worked and I had another error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message tells you file named and lines in each file.  Line 11 of the CPP and line 40 of the header file.

Delete the body (the stuff in `{}`) part of thr=e function in the header file )reppacing it with a `;`), or delete all mention of the function in the cpp file.  Both work.

Comment: Thanks internet stranger that was some of my professors code so I assumed it worked I thought it was strange to have a return in the header file. Is there ever a time when you could or would want to use a return inside a header file?

Comment: @4357 the header file is fine; methods in body of class are implicitly inline.  Cpp file is also fine.  Both together are an error.